# How prevent to destroy Activity itself?

Tags: android

In UI, there are three button for 3 types attachments(image,video,audio).After selection image/video/audio color of button changed to green.

**Problem:-**

First I click on image button to save image from SD, image successfully attached & color of button change to green.But after it click  video button to attach video then attachment complete but selection of image is remove.

when select image or video or audio  then previous selection is destroy.

**Reason:-**

Activity is destroy & re create itself.

**Question:-**

How stop to recreate activity?

Comment: You can't, its part of the Activity Lifecycle. Instead, you should read about saving the Activity state and how to recreate it from a previous state here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: it will not recreate automatically unless u call finish() or rotate your screen

Comment: @Arju i an not calling finish() method any where, & scrren orientation is only portraiot.

Comment: @Marcelo why it finish()?

Comment: can you post logcat..

Comment: @ChintanRathod there is no error in logcat.but there is some message of GC like GC_CONCURRENT freed 499K, 36% free 7062K/10887K, paused 2ms+2ms

Comment: code snippet will be appreciated if provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is short out by changing in setting.In developer option, uncheck Dont't Keep Activities option.